# bootstrap 3 grid sizes not changing col-xx-x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Guys I am unable to get the responsive grid to work properly.  I have several columns that I would like to change as the screen size adjusts.  I am only testing this in my browser (safari & firefox) on my desktop.  what I have tried is using col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-lg-1 and I only get col-xs-3 no matter what i do to the browser size.  Any thoughts?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=container-fluid>
  <h1><strong><center>Hello World!</center></strong></h1>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1>
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
             <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: url('/Users/tshon2/Desktop/rabbit.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;}

.thumbnail {
   opacity: 0.1;     
}
.thumbnail:hover {
   opacity: 0.6

}
```

Comment: You should post your HTML.

Comment: First thought: Include your code! We can't help you if you don't give us the right tools to work with. Second thought: Make sure you have jQuery included and no errors in your console.

Comment: Thanks I added the code, forgive me I'm new so this took a while.  Also note that I'm a beginner and I'm playing with all of this, so any thoughts would seriously help.

Comment: Ok first thing, don't post **all** your code... Only the relative information that is causing your specific information. No one wants to wade through a wall of text to try and debug your issue. Next, don't add your computer details in (not a huge issue for path names, but if you include your password or anything like that, it is).

Comment: Thanks Tim, I considered not posting the whole thing wasn't sure about the formatting issue.  yes I do consider security, but I was also trying to avoid various responses I'll be better the next time.

Comment: Ok here is the catch in HTML when you have div and add class to him you have to put class name into quotes :) <div class="row"... etc <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 etc"... you miss to do that so it's can't work... Also CSS style you can't write like you are, explore a little I bet you'll find how that's should be done :) GL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the enclosing quotes on a lot of your HTML attributes. Specifically, your class attributes, hence why only the first one is taking effect. Good practice is to always wrap your attributes in quotes.

Comment: So I corrected the file with the quotes and still have the same response.  Wondering if my issue is a safari bug?

Comment: The modified snippet @Xam1311 posted below works fine for me with the corrected quotes around the html attributes, even in safari. Small widths have 4 columns, medium has 6 and large has a full 12. Are you not seeing this when you resize the browser's width?

Comment: correct when I resize my browser im not seeing the changes.  running this on LATEST Macbook Pro

Comment: I made a change from one text editor to sublime and added the quotes and this seemed to work.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your style inside your body and close your brackets
Look a your code now :
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJjmWK)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1><strong><center>Hello World!</center></strong></h1>
    <div class=row>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
          <img src=/Users/tshon2/Desktop/transparent3.jpeg class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
 <style>
body { background: url('/Users/tshon2/Desktop/rabbit.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; color:#fff; background-color:#333; font-family: 'Open
Sans',Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;} .thumbnail { opacity: 0.1; } .thumbnail:hover { opacity: 0.6 }</style
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that was a separate CSS file.  I just added the contents at the end.